# Application to send funds/money to Shop vendors, Person like Google Pay, Paytm

Tags: nfc, qr-code, payment, google-pay, nfc-p2p

We would like to implement a payment solution where end users can send money to other users, merchants (e.g Walmart, shop vendors).
(Payment service to send money to shop vendors (e.g Wallmart), Person, POS)
e.g Nowadays we send money via NFC, by scanning QR Code, etc.

Is there any possibility to implement such solutions?

General Application flow:

- Customer registers on the app.
- Connect their bank account, add their Debit Card.
- Can pay to anyone via NFC, scanning QR code.

I didn't find anything yet but exploring: https://developer.mastercard.com/

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a 3rd party service (Card issuing) [Marqeta](https://www.marqeta.com/) to solve our problem. Using the API we can do the following:

- We can issue cards to Users (Virtual, Tokenized, Physical)
- Users can push cards to Google Pay, Apply Pay to use NFC payments.
- We can keep track of transactions made by the issued cards.